# How to create a delay between two chain blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My friends and I have been making a game in minecraft (java edition), and I want a title to say "Welcome", and then "To our game" after about two seconds. I created two chain command blocks next to each other, the first one saying /title @p title {"text":"Welcome"} the second one saying /title @p title {"text":"To our game"}. But it only shows "To our game". Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Use the "delay in ticks" option in the second block's settings. (Note: 1 tick 1/10 of a second.)

EDIT: This is a Bedrock Edition feature.

Comment: Is this an MCBE thing? This question is forMCJava.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to check. Yes, in BE there is a way to delay in the Cmd Block UI. I was not aware it was BE only.